# howto: Eigen Installation

Tags: ros, installation, eigen, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

This is just a brief how to on how to resolve Eigen compile time errors - which wasn't installed on my Raspberry Pi.

I kept getting the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package): 
By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has 
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but 
CMake did not find one. 

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any 
of the following names: 

Eigen3Config.cmake 
eigen3-config.cmake 

Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
"Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3" 
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been 
installed.
```

And try as I might I couldn't find a conclusive answer. Anyway these steps should solve the issue

1. Download Eigen

   hg clone https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/
2. CD into the download dir

   cd eigen
3. Create a build dir

   mkdir build
4. Configure the build

   cmake ..
5. Build the package

   make
6. Install the package

   sudo make install

And all being well that should be it!

Hope this helps

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253181/howto:-eigen-installation/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-27**:
rosdep should have installed eigen for you (if you ran it). Did you try `sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev`? Is there something wrong with the system-supplied version of Eigen on your Pi?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-01-28**:
Yep I tried installing that and had no joy. To be honest I am not quire sure what is wrong with the system supplied version - sufficed to say that a number of routes tried didn't work until i installed it from scratch

**Comment by [Abdulbaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/31967/abdulbaki/) on 2018-01-17**:
I have the same problem. could anyone solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two options:

1. Install using - sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev

Or self build, in which case use these steps:

1. Download Eigen

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/

2. CD into the download dir

cd eigen

3. Create a build dir

mkdir build

4. Configure the build

cmake ..

5. Build the package

make

6. Install the package

sudo make install

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kliffu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37461/kliffu/) on 2018-09-25**:
Does it matter, if you download Eigen, in what directory you save it?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2018-09-27**:
No shouldn't do. Step 6 will install it onto the system